# number format shorten longitude and latitude?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

orm
property name="poiLat" ormtype="big_decimal" notnull="true" persistent=true precision="16" scale="14";
property name="poiLong" ormtype="big_decimal" notnull="true" persistent=true precision="16" scale="14";

The input below would give an error due to it exceeding the length set on the properties. How in ColdFusion can I shorten the values if they exceed this.

34.037864685058594

-118.27606201171875

```
local.poiEntity.setpoiLat(local.NewlatO);
local.poiEntity.setpoiLong(local.NewlonO);
```

Comment: Can you store the latitude and longitude as a string or do you have to do calculations with the numbers?

Comment: I need them as a number yes. I cannot change the DB length. I need to somehow parse the data before it goes in the DB making sure it does not exceed this. I have tried number format but this did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i think I have this

round(local.NewlatO*10^6)/10^6;

this works out to 6 places

Comment: love it... ask a question... answer it yourself gain a reputation.

Comment: well someone may tell me this cal is wrong so ill leave it up just in case. I cannot see any rounding functions in cf native, correct me if i'm wrong. running cf9.

Comment: Yeah ... I was going to suggest trim(numberformat(local.newlat,'___.000000'))  a little klunky using a format function but works usually.

Comment: Please do answer your own question if you have the best answer!  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/